# Driver Canon Scanner Lide 210

Tags: drivers, canon, scanner

Pls Help me to find driver CAnon Scan LIDE 210.

any one can support a link for driver canon scan lide 210. OS ubuntu 12.04 LTS , linux

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Canon Lide 210 scanner appears to be [fully supported by SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-mfgs-cvs.html#Z-CANON).

It should therefore work out of the box with the [sane-genesys](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sane-genesys.5.html) driver provided by the sane common libraries.